# excelstyles values in exportOptions aren't working?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

This seems like the correct way to set the `exportOptions` object properties, but it's not working for me. Can someone explain why?

```js
exportOptions:{  
    ignoreColumn: [0,0],    
    fileName: '阅卷结果',  
    worksheetName: 'sheet1',    
    tableName: '阅卷结果',  
    excelstyles: ['background-color', 'color', 'font-size', 'font-weight']
}
```

Comment: .... More accessible? The answer is because of the character usage but hopefully someone will answer with a more complete question

Comment: I set it like this: excelstyles: ['Green', '#0000FF', '14', 'font-weight'] but the 'Green', '#0000FF', '14'  all does't work,so what i want to konw is how to set those values and make them work well

Comment: This seems like a valid question, but maybe you can expand your code example/explanation? I'm surprised no one has provided you with an answer. Also, if you resolved the issue on your own, please answer your own question for posterity!